# Map overlay - Google streetmap not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps, nexus-s

Complete beginner here so forgive me.

Porting an iOS App over to Android. We have custom image tiles laid over google maps. On iOS the streetmap displays as usual outside of our custom image tiles however on the Android version it is only showing a blank grid and we can't figure it out. The location works however it's just not showing the map.

We've tried a couple of different devices and the issue is the same across the board.

Any suggestions? If there is more info that I can provide that might help narrow the issue down, just ask.

*EDIT*: The device we are testing it on is a HTC. Apparently it works on a Nexus. Known compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your `MapView` is not loading standard map tiles, either:

- you do not have the `INTERNET` permission, or
- you do not have an Internet connection, or
- you are not using the right Maps API key for the signing key